# How to use limit and offset in SQL IN operator subquery?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-in

For example:

```
SELECT groupdate
FROM ccl9t_az_articles
WHERE groupdate IN (
   SELECT * FROM ccl9t_az_articles LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2
)
GROUP BY groupdate
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Improved the formatting of query for easier reading. Make the question in title already if possible and do not repeat it in question itself. Do not put things like `in PHP` if this is just plain SQL stuff. If it is PHP stuff specific, add PHP tag also.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data structure, some example data and the result you want to get. Maybe what you are trying to do doesn't need this sub query with the `IN` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error display above code returns the following

> MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

The problem was fixed by changing the above code to:

```
    SELECT * FROM ccl9t_az_articles as group1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT groupdate FROM ccl9t_az_articles LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2
) 
as group2 ON group1.groupdate = group2.groupdate GROUP BY group1.groupdate
```